# "Connection to server timed out"

Tags: psn

So I was gonna buy some more episodes for telltales the walking dead when it asked me to add my billing information, so I did and I made sure I had put everything right then when I hit confirm, "Connection to the server has timed out", I tried this multiple times adding each piece of information correctly and it still came up with the same message. Also, this happened when I tried to log into my old account which Iam not sure still had credit card into, I'm pretty sure I didn't add any in the first place but I wanted to check and it came up with the same message when I tried to use the old email I had for that account. Someone please help me I'm having a breakdown

Comment: If being unable to buy The Walking Dead is giving you a breakdown, you might not be able to cope with actually playing it.

Comment: This sounds like an error with their servers. Wait until tomorrow and try again.

Comment: Alright thanks, it could be something to do with that big hacking thing going around I guess